How can action on clientside dispatch action on serverside?
I have a theme switch toggle on the top AppBar which is a client component.

The main layout is SSR and uses the nextjs App router. It has theme settings <ThemeProvider theme={lightOrDarkTheme}>. Prior to App router/SSR I was able to use the cookie I set in the TopAppBar component to affect the theme change in layout file. With SSR, the cookie which is set and I can see in the browser is not accessible by server.  Cookie is on the client side, the layout.jsx file cannot read the cookie and hence the theme toggle does not work.

I would appreciate tips on how to achieve this.

I do not want to 'use client' at a top level such as layout.jsx as it defeats the purpose of SSR.
I also do not want to change TopAppBar to use server as it has way too much client code such as useEffect, mui styles ...

Here is layout.jsx
import {lightTheme, darkTheme} from '@/components/theme';
import TopAppBar from '@/components/ui/topAppBar';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
const cookieStore = cookies();

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
  }) {
    
    const cookieDark = cookieStore.get('darkTheme').value;
    const theme = cookieDark=="true"? darkTheme: lightTheme;
    ....
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

And here is TopAppBar code:
'use client'
...
export default function TopAppBar() {
...
  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setCookie('darkTheme',cookies.darkTheme == "true"? false: true, { path: '/' });
    setDarkState(cookies.darkTheme == "true"? false: true);
  };

Edit: Adding screenshot showing that cookie value is always false on cookies from next/header. Left: Browser (Client) and Right (Server console)


Hope this will be useful for someone else. Seems to be a bug in nextJs?
This strangely does not work (This is the way shown the next js docs)
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
const cookieStore = cookies();

    export default function RootLayout({
      ...
        
        const cookieDark = cookieStore.get('darkTheme'); //This does not synch when cookies on browser changes

However, if you directly use cookies.get(), it works
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export default function RootLayout({
   ...
    const cookieDark = cookies().get('darkTheme'); //This synchs when cookies on browser changes



the layout.jsx file cannot read the cookie and hence the theme toggle
does not work.

you can.
you can access cookies from server side, nextJs have a function for this.
reference : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies.

Unfortunately this is incorrect. These are server cookies. As soon as page refreshes this value is gone. I have tried and tested this.

there're no 'server cookies' or 'client cookies' ,  i have no idea from what your 'cookiesStore' is , but i assume its some custom hook, who uses document.Cookie under the hood.
You just need to properly record the value of cookies, how long they live, etc.  I implemented something similar a few months ago, and everything worked fine, actually I did it to get “initial state on server” and get rid of flashlight on first load.
i don't know what you actualy 'tried' and 'tested'  you're not providing any screens, and say just "this is not correct/work".

I have added a screenshot - left side is the browser which shows its true. The same cookie on server side is always false because its value updated on client side is not synched on server side. Your answer is just a link to official docs and says you can access the cookies but my question is very specific - How do actions on client dispatch an action on server? As you can see in the screenshot, client and server side have different values. So there are client side and server side values for cookies !

you can set it like this :
const date = new Date()
date.setMounth(date.getMounth() + 1)
document.cookie =theme='${theme}; expires=${date.toUTCString()}; or something like this, maybe you also need to add samesite=strict .

again, there's NO 'server cookies' or 'client cookies' ,  that's my bad, i forget to mention: you should add in your cliend side handler router.refresh() to refresh tour current route. or as you name it your 'server cookies'.
P.S. // but I thought you'd know that you'd need some way to let the server know that the cookie value has changed.

Also, let's not be children, first you have a missing value, and then you write that it still exists, but it is stale, and you need to synchronize the state between the client and the server.

The value set on the client side is missing from server side as you can see in the screenshot. Also router refresh does nothing as even upon manual refresh the value set on client side is missing on the server side and value does not propogate. Sounds like you just link to docs and throwing darts in the dark. Thats not how stack overflow works. If I post a question without code, I would get down voted. Likewise, you cannot just link to docs as an answer as links can move in future !
